# How to access SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-express

The problem: I'm getting this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server)

Program files shows this:

```
MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS
MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS
MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS01
```

I can access `MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS01` from SSMS 17.9.1, but all of my databases are in `MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS`.

Installation:

- SQL Server Management Studio 17.9.1
- Visual Studio 2019 16.2.1

How can I access the databases in `MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: You cannot have two unnamed instances on the same computer. It would appear you had an unnamed instance of 2016, then installed 2017 in upgrade mode replacing the 2016, then installed another (named) instance of 2017. Look in the default instance of 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Yes, that's probably what I did. I installed the named instance of 2017 as an experiment because I could not see my "old" (SQL Server 2016) databases after the upgrade. 
What I want to do is to clean up the mess that I made by migrating all my old work to a single SQL Server 2017 instance.  Any suggestions?

Comment: " Look in the default instance of 2017."
Good idea, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that "for some reason" SQL Server Services for SQL Server express was not running.

After I used services.msc to start it, I was able to open the SQL Server 13 engine (SQL Server 2016) and see all of my "old" databases.

Thanks to Vivek Janakiraman for providing a solution on the MSDN SQL Server forum.